# how do you fix this error mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm not sure how to address this issue:

EDIT: can someone just edit my code with the corrections because this is due tmrw.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login-registration-php\login-registration-php-new\dbconnect.php:6
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login-registration-php\login-registration-php-new\index.php(4):
>   require_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login-registration-php\login-registration-php-new\dbconnect.php
>   on line 6

```
    <?php

// this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
// but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost,nathan,password);
$dbcon = mysql_select_db(dbtest);

if ( !$conn ) {
    die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}

if ( !$dbcon ) {
    die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: by moving forward to new libraries:- `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`:-https://prnt.sc/gubvir

Comment: Do some search on google you will get why there is an error. Don't post question without any effort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: `Don't post question without any effort` When pos(t)ing a question, show what effort you invested. (Show a bit of effort to get the error message formatted readably: add two trailing blanks to each line. In due time, digest the editing help.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check extension=mysqli.so and extension=mysql.so both uncomment in your php.ini.

Comment: what does that mean?-

Comment: are you able to open phpmyadmin ?

Comment: please run phpinfo(); and post that. The mysql.so module is definitely not loaded. 
Do you have extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/modules/" in php.ini? Does the file /usr/lib/php/modules/mysql.so exist?
If so apache must be using a different php.ini than /etc/php/php.ini. You can see that in phpinfo. (Loaded Configuration File)